# Spring Data elastic search with out entity fields

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring data elastic search, Now my document do not have any static fields, and it is accumulated data per qtr, I will be getting ~6GB/qtr (we call them as versions). Lets say we get 5GB of data in Jan 2021 with 140 columns, in the next version I may get 130 / 120 columns, which we do not know, The end user requirement is to get the information from the database and show it in a tabular format, and he can filter the data. In MongoDB we have **`BasicDBObject`**, do we have anything in **springboot** **elasticsearch**

I can provide, let say 4-5 columns which are common in every version record and apart from that, I need to retrieve the data without mentioning the column names in the pojo, and I need to use filters on them just like I can do in MongoDB

```
List<BaseClass> getMultiSearch(@RequestBody Map<String, Object>[] attributes) {
     Query orQuery = new Query();
     Criteria orCriteria = new Criteria();
     List<Criteria> orExpression =  new ArrayList<>();
     
    for (Map<String, Object> accounts : attributes) {
       Criteria expression = new Criteria();
       accounts.forEach((key, value) -> expression.and(key).is(value));
       orExpression.add(expression);
     }
     orQuery.addCriteria(orCriteria.orOperator(orExpression.toArray(new Criteria[orExpression.size()])));
     return mongoOperations.find(orQuery, BaseClass.class);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an entity class for example like this:

```java
public class GenericEntity extends LinkedHashMap<String, Object> {
}
```

To have that returned in your calling site:

```java
public SearchHits<GenericEntity> allGeneric() {
    var criteria = Criteria.where("fieldname").is("value");
    Query query = new CriteriaQuery(criteria);
    return operations.search(query, GenericEntity.class, IndexCoordinates.of("indexname"));
}
```

But notice: when writing data into Elasticsearch, the mapping for new fields/properties in that index will be dynamically updated. And there is a limit as to how man entries a mapping can have (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-settings-limit.html). So take care not to run into that limit.